# Smaller tyre width increases racing motorcycle speeds

Tags: friction

Is it beneficial to fit the smallest width tyre possible to a racing motorcycle? This would reduce overall weight, unsprung weight, rotating mass. All these lead to increased acceleration and improve the ability of the suspension to keep the tyres in contact with the road.

Secondly this would decrease the offset encountered when leant over during a turn, decreasing lean angle compared to a larger tyre for the same center of mass offset.

As friction is not affected by the surface area this shouldn't reduce the peak cornering speed available. The downside is that the tyre will suffer faster degradation due to deformation and reduced thermal capacity. This would limit the use to only race bikes with a short required lifespan.

Is there a failure in this reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

Motorcycle tire & wheel design is an exercise in tradeoffs, as follows.

Keeping the tire in constant contact with the road despite the unevenness of the pavement requires minimization of unsprung mass (tire, wheel, fork lowers or swing arms, brake assembly). However, if we reduce the diameter of the tire/wheel combination to achieve this, we get a suspension system that will catch hard on potholes of a certain critical size. Knowing the typical size distribution of potholes puts a practical lower limit on how much the tire and wheel diameter can be shrunk.

Furthermore, the less the tire mass, the hotter it will get under repeated hard cornering and the faster it will wear out. The need to finish a race with enough rubber in contact with the road to let the tire do its job right up to the end also places a practical lower limit to tire size.

Racing bikes spend so much of their road time at extreme bank angles that optimum tire design pushes the tire into the shape of a thick torus so it can grab the pavement even when fully heeled over and basically running on its sidewalls. In fact, most of the other design considerations are secondary to this one, and in general terms this means that the best-performing racing tires are fat, wide "doughnuts" that are smaller in diameter that a typical non-race tire.

This also means that the design of these tires has already evolved significantly with the passage of years and at present is very near optimum. It is unlikely that reducing the width of a racing bike tire would represent enough of an advance in performance as to be worthwhile.